# We have lots of database migration files - should we keep them?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-migration

We have around 100 database migration files. Many of them make schema changes which are irreversible. There are also later migrations which change or remove tables which were created in earlier migrations.

We are creating new databases straight from the schema.rb file, so we were wondering if there is any reason to keep the full set of migrations?

We would create a new migration which is based on our existing schema.rb.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, what you're proposing is considered a best practice.

I've done this with my old apps several times. You'll want to back your migrations up somewhere until you're satisfied all is well, of course, this is an important part of application maintenance - if you have a lot of old migrations, it can take forever to do a `db:reset` or to get a new development environment running.

Comment: We've tried finding somewhere were this was talked about - do you know of any sites or resources that goes into detail about rails/database best practices?

Comment: @roo I've seen a few "best practices" sites, but none of them seem to address this issue specifically. I picked up on this as a best practice after discussing it with some fellow Rubyists at a local hackathon; hardly scientific but certainly peer-reviewed. :) If I were to argue for this case as a best-practice, I'd say that it doesn't make sense to clutter any of your codebase - migrations included - with history that no one can use. If someone wants to read the database history for their own education, Git will have you covered; no reason for it to be in the working branch.

Comment: Yeah, we pretty much came to the same conclusion too. Good to know that others have had the same conversation :)

Comment: Did you ever find any 'best practice' tuts that go into detail on this matter?

Comment: The argument that `db:reset` will take forever is false, `rake db:reset` and `rake db:setup` already use the `schema.rb` (or `structure.sql`). That said: removing old clutter does make sense :)

Answer (score 5):

I use `rake db:setup` and `rake db:reset` exclusively (never `rake db:migrate`) to install a new database, on a production server or on a new development machine. Those commands already use the `schema.rb` or `structure.sql` to recreate the database.

That said, it is really easy to make a copy of `schema.rb`, use that as a new starting-point and delete all the old migrations.

I prefer to keep my migrations for historic purposes, but that is a matter of taste.